# i want to store data in encyption and decryption using nodejs and mogodb with searching chat feature like if type n get all resullt with n like regex

Tags: node.js, mongodb, search, encryption, chat

This is my schema where i want to encrypt and decrypt name.

```js
courseSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name:{
        type:String,
        required: true,
        
    },  

const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const mongooseFieldEncryption = require("mongoose-field-encryption").fieldEncryption;

courseSchema.plugin(mongooseFieldEncryption, { 
     fields: ["name" , "courseType"], 
     secret: encKey,
     saltGenerator: function (secret) {
       return "1234567890123456"; 
     
     },
   });
```

I've tried all methods. but still stuck i want search functionlity on encyption data without decrypted nd its accepted regex like if i want hello and user type h its return hello.

Comment: If you can partially match the encrypted field's original text using a regex, that would mean that you can _determine_ the original text, which in turn means the text wasn't really encrypted.

Comment: Thankyou for intersted my question @Joe i was tell without decrypted all data just use regex as well get return only hello from db if i type h . now if i type h its return empty array. i dont want to decypted all collection first then compare or filter with regax or orignal text thats my requirement. i used all libraries mention in code .

Comment: Using a regex to match an encrypted field is unlikely to every work.  There is a possibility to use [queryable encryption](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/queryable-encryption/#queryable-encryption) on the client side

Comment: i am using this but still not working can you please share any tutorial or custom code with same @Joe .  i am tryed all methode but not getting desire output.

Comment: MongoDB's queryable encryption only supports equality (i.e. exact match) query: https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/mongodb-announces-queryable-encryption

Comment: that means if i want to use Regex then decrypted all messages first right but what if i have 1000000+ messages then decrypt all it bad practice and its take lot of time.

Comment: This means that if require regex search is required, the fields should not be encrypted.